# App_Web_XXXXXXXX.X.cs type or namespace not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a web application that is giving me type or namespace not found errors. The bizarre thing is that the errors are happening in an auto-generated file App_Web_XXXXXXXX.X.cs. How can I figure out which file is auto-generating this file so I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I hit this today using VS2013 and MVC4.

In my case I had added a new Model class, referenced it in a couple of places (a view and partial view) and then excluded the class and the referencing files from the solution / project.  When everything was excluded I could not get the project to compile.  I added the class and referencing files back in (e.g. "included" them) and then it built just fine.

I subsequently excluded the files that referenced the new class and it rebuilt successfully.

I then excluded the class and it failed again.

Then I included the class and commented all its code out and the compiler returned errors from the referencing files, which were **excluded**.  Very strange.  So apparently excluding files from the solution doesn't prevent them from being picked up during builds.

What ended up working for me was to simply make a backup of the files and delete them rather than excluding them.

HTH,

Andy

Comment: Great, thanks this is still a problem in VS2015 and MVC5